# Using github actions to create a .zip file in main branch

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

Currently I have this action which compresses a folder to a zip file:

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
  To-Zip:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout 
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      
      - name: Create ankiaddon
        run: zip -r -q folder.zip folder
```

but I want to commit this new `folder.zip` to the main branch, what are the steps for that?

Comment: Build artifacts generally shouldn't be stored in version control. If you just want a demo to be downloadable form your repository, use releases with attachments. If you want to publish a library, use a package manager.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub-actions%5D+artifacts

Answer (score 0):

Add the following step:

```
  - name: Commit and push
    uses: EndBug/add-and-commit@v7
    with:
      add: '["folder.zip"]'
      message: 'My commit message'
      push: true
```